# tensorflow.train.string_producer return nothing

Tags: string, input, tensorflow, producer

I'm tring to train my own images data using cifar-10 cnn model,the debug information is below .
[image: tensorflow-string-producer]

the debug location is :

```html
 # Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

  # Read examples from files in the filename queue.
  read_input = read_cifar10(filename_queue)
  reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32)
```

So my question is,why there is nothing in filename_queue ?Thanks!

Comment: is that menu from tensorboard?

Comment: Are you running the Queue from within the Session ?  Those are Queue operations.

Comment: @titus no ,this is debug information.

Comment: @fabrizioM, the operation ran in session by default.

Answer (score 0):

When debugging the source code of cifar-10,i found there is nothing in its queue either. It seems that the content within queue was filled later